# Android: Dynamically add ImageView to Linearlayout inside Adapter's onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, dynamic, android-recyclerview

So I have cardview which contains a textview and linearlayout, and inside the linearlayout I want to add variable number of image views (These views will be holding app icons). How can I achieve this inside RecyclerView's onBindViewHolder.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9O7n.png]

Code for CardView (Here the linearlayout will hold imageviews):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="4sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_app_icons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </LinearLayout>

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/main_page_toggle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="5sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Code for Adapter (Which I am trying to implement):

```
public class ProfileListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfileListAdapter.ProfileViewHolder>{


    private List<ProfileContentsFull> pcf;

    ProfileListAdapter(List<ProfileContentsFull> pcf) {
        this.pcf = pcf;
    }

    @Override
    public ProfileViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_main_page, parent, false);
        return new ProfileViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProfileViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.profileName.setText(pcf.get(position).getProfileName());
        holder.linearLayout.set
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }


    public static class ProfileViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView profileName;
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;
        public ToggleButton toggle;
        public ProfileViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            profileName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_app_icons);
            toggle = (ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_page_toggle);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout containing the recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.retr0spect.quit.social.media.addiction.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/main_page_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please update your original post with your code?

Comment: Made the edits.

Comment: Where is the RecyclerView in your layout?

Comment: It seems to me that instead of a LinearLayout which holds the ImageViews, you can use a RecyclerView to hold the ImageViews.

Comment: RecyclerView is holding all the cardviews. Ok, so how can I proceed with making the RecyclerView hold imageviews inside the adapter?

Comment: @Retr0spect101 number of imageview is static(always 3) or its dynamic?

Comment: It is dynamic, they could be zero or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `ImageView` dynamically into  `LinearLayout` like below.

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(holder.linearLayout.getContext());
holder.linearLayout.addView(imageView);
```

And you can add multipal `ImageView` by putting above lines within Loop. `ImageViews` are added only in `vertical` or `Horizontally`.

Comment: How can I get reference to 'linearLayout.getContext()' inside onBindViewHolder?

Comment: Thanks I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProfileViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.profileName.setText(pcf.get(position).getProfileName());
        LayoutInflater layoutinflater=(LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        holder. linearLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int j = 1; j < pcf.get(position).getImageArray().size(); j++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "&& J :" + j);
            // inflate the layout
            convertView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_images, null, false);
            convertView.setId(j);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
            //set image here
            holder.linearLayout.addView(convertView);
        }
    }
```

adapter_images.xml

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```